# Converting list of string to bytes in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, list, queue, byte

I have been trying to convert a list of string elements to bytes so that I can send it to the server.
Below is the snippet for my code:-

```
    ls_queue=list(q.queue)
    print("Queue converted to list elements:::",ls_queue)

    encoded_list=[x.encode('utf-8') for x in ls_queue]
    print("Encoded list:::",encoded_list)
    s.send(encoded_list)
```

The output I get is:

```
 Encoded list::: [b'madhav']
 Exception in Tkinter callback
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in 
 __call__
 return self.func(*args)
 File "Practice_Client_Server.py", line 149, in Word_Append_Window
  s.send(encoded_list)
 TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

I can see that it is getting converted to bytes but it still gives the error while trying to encode and send. Can someone take a look as to what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a `list` object when `send` is expecting a `bytes` one, that happened when u converted the elements of the `list` into `bytes` but not the `list` container. What u can do is serialize it as a `JSON` string and then convert it to `bytes`, for example:

```py
import json

l = ['foo', 'bar']
l_str = json.dumps(l)
l_bytes = l_str.encode('utf-8')
send(l_bytes)
```

Then u can read it on your server doing the opposite:

```
reconstructed_l = json.loads(l_bytes.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thank you. I did try this and it works for me. Now my list is getting converted to bytes. But it is still not allowing me to send it to my server. 
While using the send(l_bytes) command, it gives me a socket timeout error.